# How to get tabs in unix session on putty

Tags: shell, unix

I have used an script in past that enabled me to connect me to multiple unix machines, much like using a tab. Its just that I forgot the name of the script. Anyone know about it?

Comment: I answered this, but I'm considering flagging it for a move to SuperUser or something too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're referring to [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which is a terminal multiplexer that allows you to have multiple virtual terminal windows in a single normal terminal window (ala PuTTY).  I'd suggest [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) as a better alternative, but they're essentially the same.  There are other solutions that will allow you to do tabs in the terminal client, but that depends on your OS (I'm assuming you're on Windows), and you'd have to initiate each connection individually.  screen/tmux is the way to go most of the time.

Comment: Thanks, it was screen, wont forget now :)